# CSS OnHover- Change another element's property as well as itself

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a sidebar menu and want it to be partially collapsing, which means I have to show text on hover and hide the text when not hovering. I know another question has been asked about changing another element's property on hover, but I'm having trouble changing itself and another property.

General HTML layout:

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1d326b; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar:hover > .text {
    display: block; /*Supposed to display text*/
  width: 150px; /*Expands the sidebar*/
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
   <!--more containers...-->
   <!--text below is deeply nested-->
   <p class="text">Displayed Text</p>
</div>
```

Is there a pure css solution to this problem? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is the animation for the width, if that's what you want just remove `> .text` from the hover selector:

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1d326b; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #FFF; 
}

.sidebar:hover {
  display: block; /*Supposed to display text*/
  width: 150px; /*Expands the sidebar*/
}

.text {
  width: 150px;
  display: none;
}

.sidebar:hover .text {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
   <!--more containers...-->
   <!--text below is deeply nested-->
   <p class="text">Displayed Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would doing something like this be what you're looking for?

```
.text{
  display: none;
}

.sidebar:hover > .text {
    display: block; /*Supposed to display text*/
    width: 150px; /*Expands the sidebar*/
}
```

Comment: That's what I have in my css, but the text doesn't get displayed.

Comment: You havet he `.text {dispaly: none;}` part?  I have it working here on jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/dx45yLhf/1/   is that what you want?

Comment: What I found is that only one property is updated, no matter what I try. For example I can get the sidebar to expand but not the text to display, and vice versa. But I can't seem to get both.

Comment: Can you add some more of your code of what you think you want it to do, you can put it in a jsfillde and I can take a look. I'm not sure what exactly the issue is with the info I have now.

Comment: Your solution is fine for just displaying the text, however the sidebar doesn't expand. If I replace > with a comma like in this jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/gtofdbcw/) the sidebar expands but the text doesn't show. I'm trying to get the text to show and expand the sidebar.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 .sidebar .text {
   visibility: hidden;
 }
 .text:hover {
    display: block; 
    width: 150px; 
 }
```

Comment: The text doesn't seem to display

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.